# Дублирующиеся запросы от @property в Django Model

Tags: django

Для подзапроса создал `@property` в моделе `Transaction`. Но при обращении создаётся множество похожих запросов. Как это пофиксить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py

```
class PayerPaymentSource(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    payer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source_details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"processing"."payer_payment_source"'


class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # service_instance = models.ForeignKey(ServiceInstance, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_source = models.ForeignKey(PayerPaymentSource, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def bank_card_details(self):
        return PayerPaymentSource.objects.filter(payer_id=self.payment_source.payer_id,
                                                 payment_type_id='bank_card_details').values_list('source_details', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"processing"."transaction"'
```

views.py

```
paymentsss = Transaction.objects.all().select_related('currency', 'payment_source__payment_type','deal__service__contractor')
print(payment.bank_card_details)
```

Comment: `print(payment.bank_card_details)` вы, вероятно, в цикле делаете для каждого элемента `paymentsss`?

Comment: Вообще такой фильтр через @property не рекомендуют делать. Если вы его хотите инкапсулировать подобным образом, то переопределять стандартный менеджер на свой и в нем реализовать выборку

Comment: @Александр, тут немного кривоватая схема хранения данных. Поэтому мне надо сделать SELF JOIN таблицы с условием. Пытаюсь накостылить это... Вот один из вариантов был, как получить желаемый результат, но на каждую транзакцию получается отдельный запрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 варианта:
1. [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)
2. Кэшируйте запросы на уровне БД

Comment: Заменил на cached_property и ничего не изменилось. Надо ещё что-то добавить/дописать?

Comment: Можно ли как-то иначе сделать это? Sql-функции можно писать в джанге? Чтобы реализовать этот запрос, как подзапрос.

Comment: писать можно, но не рекомендуется

Comment: Тут немного кривоватая система, так что я сомневаюсь, что есть другие варианты

Comment: Я думаю можно попробовать annotate

Comment: Насчёт annotate не уверен. В чистом SQL нужные результат вообще делается с SELF JOIN PaymentSource по payer_id с парой alias-ов.  `LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."payer_payment_source" AS "psc" ON ("ps"."payer_id" = "psc"."payer_id") AND "psc"."payment_type_id" = 'bank_card_details' `